# How to show popup dialog using jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I looked in the [API reference of popup](http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/),

and a bit below there's some examples, "tooltips", "menu", ... , "dialog", "photo".

How can I create the popup dialog as their example? there's no reference and explanation about it.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

simple popup structure:

Button to open popup

```
<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a>
```

Structure:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">
  <p>This is a completely basic popup, no options set.<p>
</div>
```

Dialog popup

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">

  <div data-role="header">
    <h1>Popup!</h1>
  </div>

  <div data-role="content">
    <p>Advanced popup</p>
    <a href="#" data-role="button" data-rel="back">I understand - close popup</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

You can place any element inside content div. and remember, page div should be direct parent of popup div.

Comment: And how would you open the popup programmatically? ie. not by clicking on a link.